# Checking normality for quasi compact schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $X$ be a quasi compact scheme. 
We know that any point on $X$ is a generization of a close point. 
Could someone possibly explain me why it then follows that to check if $X$ is
normal, it suffices to check the normality at closed points? Thanks!

Comment: Dear user, how do you know that each point is a generization of some closed point?

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg This was an exercise I had to do for quasi compact schemes. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, thank you for your quick answer. I asked because the result in your exercise doesn't seem to be mentioned in the standard books. Your exercises are  rather sophisticated, apparently!

Comment: Interesting! It is Ravi Vakil's notes :) Also thank you for your answer, I will go through it!

Comment: Ah, that explains it: his fantastic notes are extremely original and contain a wealth of results not to be found elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

0) This is a rather subtle question.
It is indeed true, as Robert pertinently remarks, that any localization of an integrally closed domain is integrally closed.
But what about schemes?

1) First of all, what is a normal scheme?
Answer: it is a scheme $X$ such that for each $x\in X$ the local ring $\mathcal O_{X,x}$ is a normal domain.
So it seems that  it is enough to prove that such a point $x$ has a closed point $x_0\in \overline {\{x\}}$ in its closure , and  then to conclude that $\mathcal O_{X,x}$, being a localization of $\mathcal O_{X,x_0}$, is also integrally closed.

2) However this idea alone doesn't lead to a correct proof because there exist (very counterintuitively!) schemes which have no closed point at all!

3) This is why we have the hypothesis that the scheme $X$ is quasi-compact: 
it is then a reasonably  easy consequence that $X$ does have a closed point.
Since any closed subset of a quasi-compact space is also quasi-compact we can now prove the result : indeed given $x\in X$ the closure $\overline {\{x\}}$ is quasi-compact and thus contains a closed point $x_0$.
We can then legitimately apply the reasoning suggested in 1)  .

Answer (score 0):

Because if you are an integrally closed ring $A$, so are all your localizations at prime (resp. maximal) ideals (and reciprocally). So for quasi-compact schemes, you can check normality at closed points.

Comment: Hi! Could you possibly explain why it suffices to only check at the closed points? Thanks!

Comment: @user192077 To get the stalks at the non-closed points you can take a closed point and localize its local ring. And integral closure respects localization. I think those are the main points.

Comment: @Hoot Cold you possibly explain a bit on why we can take the stalk at the closed point to get the stalk of a non-closed point?

Comment: @user192077 If $P \subset Q$ are primes of a ring $A$ then $A_P$ is the localization of $A_Q$ at $PA_Q$. I think. So, of course, you need to know that there is some $Q$ that really is closed in the whole scheme and not just $\operatorname{Spec} A$.