# Localization of a closed point in a quasicompact scheme

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, schemes

Let $X$ be a quasicompact scheme. Then we have that for any $x\in X$, there exists a closed point $x_0\in\{\overline{x}\}$. I saw in an answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1122305/checking-normality-for-quasi-compact-schemes) question that $\mathcal{O}_x$ (the stalk at the point $x$) is a localization of $\mathcal{O}_{x_0}$.

Why is this true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $U= \operatorname{Spec}A$ is an affine open of $X$ containing $x_0.$ Note that $U$ also contains $x$: if $x\not\in U,$ then we have
$$
\overline{\{x\}} = (X\setminus U)\cap\left(\bigcap_{C\textrm{ closed}, C\ni x}C\right).
$$
However, this implies $x_0\in X\setminus U.$

Now, we may suppose that $X = \operatorname{Spec}A.$ Suppose $\mathfrak{p}$ (respectively, $\mathfrak{p}_0$) is the prime of $A$ corresponding to $x$ (respectively, $x_0$). What does it mean for $\mathfrak{p}_0\in\overline{\{\mathfrak{p}\}}$? Well, since $\overline{\{\mathfrak{p}\}} = V(\mathfrak{p}),$ this means that $\mathfrak{p}\subseteq\mathfrak{p}_0.$ Remember that $\mathcal{O}_{X,\mathfrak{p}}\cong A_{\mathfrak{p}},$ and similarly for $\mathfrak{p}_0.$ However, if $\mathfrak{p}\subseteq\mathfrak{p}_0,$ then $A_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is indeed a further localization of $A_{\mathfrak{p}_0}$: you simply localize at $A_{\mathfrak{p}_0}\setminus\mathfrak{p}A_{\mathfrak{p}_0}$.